# Combining some values columns in a pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, pivot-chart

If I have a pivot chart with a single axis, and three values columns (from two sheets), is it possible for me to combine two of these three values columns. In other words, in the below chart, can I combine the two New columns.

[image]

I've tried using Grouping, but that only applies to the axis, not the values. I tried swapping the x and y axis, but as they are still Values columns, I still couldn't group them.

Comment: @pnuts: It's not a duplicate. I created a single unique common attribute and joined them.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Calculated Item (say `Sum New`) with Formula:

```
='New - Created' +'New - Converted'
```

then filter out the columns not required for display.

Comment: This looks like it could do what I want. I'm currently trying to find a way to make the Calculated Item field useable though. It's greyed out. A few google searches haven't helped yet. My data is all within the Excel sheet (no connections to outside). Any thoughts?

Comment: Yeah. I've selected one of the Row Labels, gone to Analyze - Fields, Items & Sets, but it's greyed out. All data is from within the worksheet and it's not in protected mode

Comment: Yes, I've tried selecting row and column labels. See my question edit.

Comment: Hmm. I can get a Calculated Item if I don't use the Data Model, i.e. if I have data from one sheet instead of two. Of course, doing this means I don't have all the data necessary to create the Calculated Item in the first place.

Comment: Got it. I can't seem to do this using a Data Model in Excel, but it can be done easily using PowerPivot (and [thanks to this question too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901659/powerpivot-adding-calculated-item-to-a-field)). Thank you for your help.