# How to return the minimum date per account for a specific order type

Tags: sql, powerpivot, dax, powerquery

- I have a list of orders which come in two types (A and B).
- Every account has at least one type A order.
- Multiple orders of each type can exist on an account.
- For each account, I need to know the minimum Order_Date of all type A orders on that account.

Should I do this in SQL, powerquery, or powerpivot?
I would prefer to calculate it in powerquery or powerpivot. 
Any ideas?

Comment: If your data is in a database, I would use it, this would be very simple in sql. Can you post some code? What have your tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just going to make some basic assumptions about your table structure. Something like this should work:

```
SELECT Account.Name, MIN(Order_date) FirstOrderDate
FROM Account LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders on Account.AccountId = Orders.OrderId
AND Orders.Type='A'
GROUP BY Account.Name
```

Comment: Is this not going to return the oldest order of the whole table?

Comment: I think we have a winner. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM accounts,order
WHERE accounts.id = order.account_id and order.id in
(SELECT TOP 1 id FROM order
 WHERE type = "A"
 ORDER BY date);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption :** There is one to many relationship between [Order] and [Account] tables.

**Steps:**

1. Create relationship between [Order] and [Account] table in PowerPivot. Make sure arrow is pointing from [Order] to [Account].
2. Create a table [OrderType], if it is not already present in PowerPivot. Create relationship between [Order] and [OrderType] table in PowerPivot. Again, Make sure arrow is pointing from [Order] to [OrderType].
3. Create a Calculated Field (not Calculated Column) in table [Order] as follows,

   ```
   [Minimum Date] = min(Order[Order_Date])
   ```

Here are links explaining how to create Calculated Field in Power Pivot.[Link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901659/powerpivot-adding-calculated-item-to-a-field)    [Link-2](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculated-Fields-in-Power-Pivot-86484821-a324-4da3-803b-82fd2e5033f4)

4. Create a Power Pivot Report. Put [Order_Type] column on COLUMNS and [Account_Name] (or [Account_ID] or any other Account identifier) on ROWS. Finally add calculated field [Minimum Date] (created in step 3) on VALUES.

Answer (score 0):

Power Query can do this easily without any custom SQL.

Filter to just A orders: right click an A cell in the Type column and 
Text Filters > Equals.

Then right click AccountID and Group By for the minimum Order Date:
[image: Group By]

Some hard-coded data to show it working:

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document("AccountID,Type,Order_Date
        1,A,1/4/13
        1,A,1/5/13
        1,B,1/1/13
        2,A,5/5/13"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source),
    TypedData = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"AccountID", Int64.Type}, {"Order_Date", type date}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(TypedData, each [Type] = "A"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"AccountID"}, {{"MinDate", each List.Min([Order_Date]), type date}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```